# Simplify Oracle SQL Unions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL query I am trying to use (save/make easy future modifications to) that is essentially the same query over and over and over, `UNION`ed each time, with only minor changes to the `WHERE` clause.

I am more familiar with MS Access, which allows me to use an `IIf` statement in the `SELECT` clause to accomplish the same, but I was not sure how to do this with Oracle, so I came up with this mess instead.

Since there may be future changes in the query, such as adding or removing items from the `common.jurisdiction_td.state_cd` pull, I want to be able to reduce the overall size/repeteiveness of the query so making those changes is easier. Other values like the dates are more flexible, so I've got those plugging in as user-specified variables already. It's the more static criteria that I'm concerned about, since I don't want to have the end-user putting in the same variable for those fields 10,000 times before the next potential change.

Is there a way I can simplify this so that either the `UNION`s are reduced and/or the sub-queries are smaller, more compact, and better able to be manipulated?

I had also considered `SELECT`ing my needed fields in the top-level query, but the DB is very large and each individual step takes a few minutes to run as-is. I was worried that doing `SELECT *, '<variable field value>'` in the sub-queries would make the process run far too long. (I have not tested this method, but I have assumed it is no good. Please correct me if that's wrong!)

Also, I feel like the use of `()` is a bit overboard, but this was produced by a query builder, and I'm presenting the output of that here.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT billrevw.bill_hdr.icn),
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd,
       '<1000' AS TBC
FROM   common.jurisdiction_td,
       billrevw.bill_hdr
WHERE  ( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.icn LIKE '%00' )
         AND ((( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GAL%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GSA%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GEE%' ) )))
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.fnlzd_paid_posting_dt BETWEEN
                   '01-May-2012 0:00:00' AND '31-Jul-2012 0:00:00' )
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd <> '6' )
         AND ( common.jurisdiction_td.state_cd NOT IN (
               '139', '199', '219', '239' ) )
       )
       AND (( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd NOT IN ( 'MOD', 'NFS' ) )
               OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd IS NULL ) ))
       AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.ttl_chrg BETWEEN 0 AND 999.99 )
       AND billrevw.bill_hdr.dw_jrsdctn_row_id =
           common.jurisdiction_td.dw_jrsdctn_row_id
           (
        +
    )
GROUP  BY billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd
UNION
SELECT Count(DISTINCT billrevw.bill_hdr.icn),
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd,
       '1000-5000' AS TBC
FROM   common.jurisdiction_td,
       billrevw.bill_hdr
WHERE  ( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.icn LIKE '%00' )
         AND ((( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GAL%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GSA%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GEE%' ) )))
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.fnlzd_paid_posting_dt BETWEEN
                   '01-May-2012 0:00:00' AND '31-Jul-2012 0:00:00' )
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd <> '6' )
         AND ( common.jurisdiction_td.state_cd NOT IN (
               '139', '199', '219', '239' ) )
       )
       AND (( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd NOT IN ( 'MOD', 'NFS' ) )
               OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd IS NULL ) ))
       AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.ttl_chrg BETWEEN 1000 AND 4999.99 )
       AND billrevw.bill_hdr.dw_jrsdctn_row_id =
           common.jurisdiction_td.dw_jrsdctn_row_id
           (
        +
    )
GROUP  BY billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd
UNION
SELECT Count(DISTINCT billrevw.bill_hdr.icn),
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd,
       '5000-10000' AS TBC
FROM   common.jurisdiction_td,
       billrevw.bill_hdr
WHERE  ( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.icn LIKE '%00' )
         AND ((( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GAL%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GSA%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GEE%' ) )))
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.fnlzd_paid_posting_dt BETWEEN
                   '01-May-2012 0:00:00' AND '31-Jul-2012 0:00:00' )
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd <> '6' )
         AND ( common.jurisdiction_td.state_cd NOT IN (
               '139', '199', '219', '239' ) )
       )
       AND (( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd NOT IN ( 'MOD', 'NFS' ) )
               OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd IS NULL ) ))
       AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.ttl_chrg BETWEEN 5000 AND 9999.99 )
       AND billrevw.bill_hdr.dw_jrsdctn_row_id =
           common.jurisdiction_td.dw_jrsdctn_row_id
           (
        +
    )
GROUP  BY billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd
UNION
SELECT Count(DISTINCT billrevw.bill_hdr.icn),
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
       billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd,
       '10000-25000' AS TBC
FROM   common.jurisdiction_td,
       billrevw.bill_hdr
WHERE  ( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.icn LIKE '%00' )
         AND ((( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GAL%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GSA%' )
                  OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id LIKE 'GEE%' ) )))
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.fnlzd_paid_posting_dt BETWEEN
                   '01-May-2012 0:00:00' AND '31-Jul-2012 0:00:00' )
         AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd <> '6' )
         AND ( common.jurisdiction_td.state_cd NOT IN (
               '139', '199', '219', '239' ) )
       )
       AND (( ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd NOT IN ( 'MOD', 'NFS' ) )
               OR ( billrevw.bill_hdr.rptng_exclusn_cd IS NULL ) ))
       AND ( billrevw.bill_hdr.ttl_chrg BETWEEN 10000 AND 24999.99 )
       AND billrevw.bill_hdr.dw_jrsdctn_row_id =
           common.jurisdiction_td.dw_jrsdctn_row_id
           (
        +
    )
GROUP  BY billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_orgn_id,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.type_of_bill,
          billrevw.bill_hdr.bill_type_cd;
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all you must avoid using "or" in where clause.

second, I understand that your sql code is not full, but still I think that you can get rid of all unions and use case/decode instead.

third, I would suggest not to use tables in "from" which fields not used in "select" use in/exists instead.

consider query I've wrote

```
Select Count(Distinct Icn), t.*
  From (Select Bh.Icn
              ,Bh.Bill_Orgn_Id
              ,Bh.Type_Of_Bill
              ,Bh.Bill_Type_Cd
              ,Case
                 When Bh.Ttl_Chrg Between 0 And 999.99 Then
                  '<1000'
                 When Bh.Ttl_Chrg Between 1000 And 4999.99 Then
                  '1000-5000'
                 When Bh.Ttl_Chrg Between 5000 And 9999.99 Then
                  '5000-10000'
                 When Bh.Ttl_Chrg Between 10000 And 24999.99 Then
                  '10000-25000'
               End Tbc
          From Billrevw.Bill_Hdr Bh
         Where Bh.Icn Like '%00'
           And Substr(Bh.Bill_Orgn_Id, 1, 3) In ('GAL', 'GSA', 'GEE')
           And Bh.Fnlzd_Paid_Posting_Dt Between '01-May-2012 0:00:00' And
               '31-Jul-2012 0:00:00'
           And Bh.Bill_Type_Cd <> '6'
           And Exists
         (Select Null
                  From Common.Jurisdiction_Td j
                 Where j.State_Cd Not In ('139', '199', '219', '239')
                   And Bh.Dw_Jrsdctn_Row_Id = j.Dw_Jrsdctn_Row_Id)
           And Nvl(Bh.Rptng_Exclusn_Cd, '') Not In ('MOD', 'NFS')) t
 Group By t.Bill_Orgn_Id, t.Type_Of_Bill, t.Bill_Type_Cd, t.Tbc
```

Comment: Why not use `OR`? Thanks for the `CASE` and `IN`.

Comment: `or` is very costly

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` for ranges, even when it's (probably) a fixed-precision type.  Please use an exclusive upper-bound (`'<'`) - such as `... CASE WHEN bh.ttl_chrg >= 0 AND bh.ttl_chrg < 1000 THEN ....`.  This will also protect you if the precision _does_ change in the future.  Also, I find it difficult to believe that an `OR` is very costly; is there something in the Oracle documentation I'm not aware of?

Comment: `select * from table_name where ( :A is null or A=:A )` full table scan

`select * from table_name where :A is not null and A=:A
union all
select * from table_name where :A is null`
table scan and index access

Comment: @Babur "where :A is null" is going to be a full table scan, unless you have employed some special kind of indexing technique.

Comment: OR is not neccessarily a full table scan. Index-based methods, such as a fast full index scan, are common with OR's. An IN() is logically the same as an OR anyway, and they produce the same transformed query.